# Minikube: host-agnostic way to set / retrieve External IP

Tags: macos, ubuntu, localhost, ip, minikube

I recently did an implementation of our local environment on the basis of Minikube. In my automation scripts for env provision I relied on the fact that `minikube tunnel` exposes services with LB type at `127.0.0.1` local IP - this is what happens on my macOS.

However, a developer with Ubuntu (running under VirtualBox) complained that for him External IP is never a loopback one, it's always something from the `10.0.0.0/8` subnet.

At this point I am trying to figure out what is the best course of action:

1. Try to force somehow External IPs on all platforms to be `127.0.0.1`. IDK if possible, couldn't find anything on that.
2. Or fall back to some other way to reliably find the external IP for any given service. I assume I can use `kubectl` output to grep the External IP, but that will add overhead and latency in scripts I was hoping to avoid.

What is the cheap and reliable host-agnostic way to find External IP for any given service within the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think 1. is possible. Similar to you, I could not find any information.

I think option 2 is good, but you don't have to use `grep`. You can use `kubectl` built in [JSONPath Support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) and set IP address as variable (example in bash):

```sh
IP_ADDRESS=$(kubectl get service {your-service} -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
```

You may also use [NodePort](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#nodeport-access) and do not use `minikube tunnel` at all:

```sh
IP_ADDRESS=$(minikube ip && kubectl get service {your-service} -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}")
IP_ADDRESS=$(echo $IP_ADDRESS | sed 's/ /:/g')
```

Or get it using [`minikube service --url <service-name>` command](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#getting-the-nodeport-using-the-service-command), but the output starts with `http://`:

```sh
user@shell:~$ minikube service --url my-service
http://{ip-of-the-node}:{node-port}
```

Another option is to run in the background [`kubectl port-forward` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) at the beginning of the script and use `localhost` address everywhere, but I think previous solutions are better and more reliable.